# Should there be a no-rep-gain edit for changes less than 6 characters?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

> *Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?*

Well, the question Per se was a one-liner but I added back-ticks and corrected a typo. In my opinion, it improved the readability of the question.

I don't want a +2 but I'd like the question to be more legible, is it time to introduce a no-rep edit option and potentially let users from 1k to 2k rep range approve those?

Comment: *Well, the question per se was a one-liner.* Doesn't look like a good question then. Maybe it should be closed, not edited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The purpose of the 6 character requirement is to prevent a slew of 1-character edits from making it into the edit review process. Once you have enough rep, your edits skip the review queue and you can make 1-character edits.

So, in short, the 6-character requirement is there for other reasons, not to demand minimum effort in order to get your rep.

Comment: I came across a helpful answer today and I up-voted it.  Put the code in my application and realized one character was mucking it up.  I edited that one character (case issue; dayofWeek in one place; dayOfWeek in another) and could only submit if I changed 5 more characters.  I tried 4 different ways to change at least 5 more characters.  The first three have been rejected.  Lame.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284452/get-nth-weekday-of-month-in-c-sharp/3284486#3284486

Comment: Once you've got enough rep (2000, I think) there is no minimum character requirement. It's only there for users who are still relatively new to our moderation system.

Comment: The point is, the reviewers aren't looking at the full edit... the code doesn't compile.  About 7 out of 8 different reviewers have looked at my edit and not been able to identify that the code doesn't compile.  By me changing one character (+5) the code will work flawlessly for someone else.  But the people responsible for approving it aren't capable of seeing that.

Comment: @ iii I agree, there are cases where accepted answers have single-character typos that prevent the code from working, and no one with enough reputation to has bothered to fix said single character. Case in point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716001/reading-in-a-text-file-in-a-set-line-range/24716036#24716036 The second part of the second answer has 'readline' instead of 'readlines'

Comment: @EliezerMiron - Why have you not commented on the post pointing out this issue? Edits to code generally aren't accepted in the review queue, but a comment pointing out small typos are useful and appreciated (and occasionally result in the author updating their post).

Comment: @JDB Good point